# How can we make the underline invisible in labels of PieSlice in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I am trying to create a pie chart in QML with percentage values displayed as labels.
I am able to implement it with PieSeries and PieSlice. But the problem is that the percentage value (label) is always displayed with an underline which I dont want to be.

Tried by setting labelFont.underline property  of PieSlice to FALSE and by setting labelArmLengthFactor to 0. but there is no effect.

any help is appreciated

Please find below my main.qml code (which is loaded from main.cpp using QQmlApplicationEngine)

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtCharts 2.0

    Window {
    visible: true;
    width: 300
    height: 300
    title: qsTr("PieChart")
    ChartView{
        id:chart
        anchors.fill:parent
        backgroundColor: "black"
        PieSeries{
            id : series
            PieSlice{
                label: "40%"
                value: 40
                color: "red"
                labelColor: color
                labelVisible : true;
                labelArmLengthFactor: 0
                labelFont.underline: false
            }
            PieSlice{
                label: "60%"
                value: 60
                color: "green"
                labelColor: color
                labelVisible : true;
                labelArmLengthFactor: 0
                labelFont.underline: false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you could publish a [mcve], read [ask], review the [tour] and improve your question :).

Comment: It is not the underline of the text but is part of the line that links each piece of the Pie with the corresponding label

Comment: Is there any way around to make this line invisble in the chart ?